# Missing date in 'About this mac' window

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I'm looking for used macbook pro and found this one. Why there is no date of manufacture in 'About this mac' window? Can it be hacked mac?
Also on second screen shot there is mystical '1Tb flash storage', does it mean 1Tb SSD or why then this hard drive called 'flash storage'?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I dont know the answer, but I'm guessing custom configurations (any other than the 3 or so that apple stores carry in stock: base model, middle, and loaded) are not showing a mfr date on the about screen, possibly because they are made as they are ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other places in About this Mac, that can give you a hint, like Install date for applications.

Flash storage means SSD. Apple started selling MBP with 1Tb SSD from 2013. You can check your specific model using the [serial number at Apple](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do).

I did the check on Apple web site and it say you have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)

Here is the full report:

[image: model]

And the full specs are here https://support.apple.com/kb/SP691?locale=en_US

Comment: But is it possible to have 1Tb SSD? Also i don't see any 'more info' button.

Comment: The button is called "System Report..." in older versions of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to figure out which model of Macbook Pro that is, you can use the serial number from the screenshot.

Just enter the serial number on a site like EveryMac's Ultimate Mac Lookup and it will tell you about the Mac. For example the below link tells you that this is a Late 2013 Macbook Pro.

http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=C02LT3SLFH05

Comment: Thank you! But i'm afraid if missing date points to a fact that this mac was hacked.

Comment: Are you certain that Apple always list something there? I can't seem to find a single example of a Retina 2013 Macbook "About This Mac" on Google Images. I can however find other screenshots where that field is blank for various devices.

Comment: That field doesn't actually signify anything btw. You can edit it to say anything you want. It just grabs the string from /Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist. The serial number is more significant and more difficult (though not impossible) to change.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a custom order machine, it will not show the "year" information. Only standard off-the-shelf machines show that information, just another Apple quirk.

Comment: Sorry, that's just wrong. My tMBP was ordered custom and it still shows year just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This "feature" of showing the year in "About this Mac" didn't exist when that OS was released. I think it was added in Yosemite 10.10 or El Capitan 10.11.

Comment: Apparently not. See http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/a-closer-look-at-system-information for that windows in 10.9.2.